# Receive HTTPS POST request in NODEJS

Tags: node.js, post, https

I want to handle the POST request data in NODEJS using HTTPS. Something like below,

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var https = require('https'); 
// Create a new instance of express
var app = express()

// Tell express to use the body-parser middleware and to not parse extended bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
 //private key and certificate for secure connection (https)
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
 };
var httpsApp = https.createServer(options,app);
// Route that receives a POST request to /sms
httpsApp._events.request.post('/xyz', function (req, res) {
  -----
  some code
  -----

})

httpsApp.listen(5004, function(){
   console.log("listening on port 5004");
   logger.info("listening on port 5004");
});
```

But turns out, this only works for HTTP request. This will not give any error but it wont receive the data to be received in '/xyz'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like an Reverse-Proxy to fix this more nicely?

Comment: Not sure if Reverse-proxy will fix this issue. Any particular reason why this will work as to my knowledge reverse proxy is a proxy server which retrieve resources on behalf of client from one or more servers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to check your certificates.
I have checked this code through my certificates and they are working with https.
I m putting code here:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var https = require('https'); 
var fs = require('fs')
// Create a new instance of express
var app = express()

// Tell express to use the body-parser middleware and to not parse extended bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
 //private key and certificate for secure connection (https)
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./certificates/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./certificates/server.crt'),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
 };
var httpsApp = https.createServer(options,app);
// Route that receives a POST request to /sms
httpsApp._events.request.get('/xyz', function (req, res) {
  console.log("Works")
    res.send("working")
})

httpsApp.listen(5004, function(){
   console.log("listening on port 5004");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the certificates are not a problem. It works fine with other application. Can you do this by changing httpsApp._events.request.get() to httpsApp._events.request.post() and see if that works?

Comment: yeah it will work but for "post" method u have to enter parameters which you want to post. As "get" works, "post" will definitely works.

Comment: Yes i am doing that since morning but it just don't read the data.

Comment: do you pass req.body to pass the params?
can you show me your code. so i can help

Comment: I was receiving the params in req.query but it doesn't even print "Works" like in your case. Code inside 'xyz' function is something like this:    console.log("inside post request"); var abc = req.query.abc; console.log("abc",abc);

Comment: yup i got the same issue in post method.. still trying..i will notify you if i find any solution.

Comment: i got this solution..while using "post" method we get params same like in "get". so i will recommend u to use app.post method.
console.log("httpsApp._events.request.post",httpsApp._events.request.post)
// function (path){
//   if (method === 'get' && arguments.length === 1) {
//     // app.get(setting)
//     return this.set(path);
//   }

//   this.lazyrouter();

//   var route = this._router.route(path);
//   route[method].apply(route, slice.call(arguments, 1));
//   return this;
// }
app.post('/xyz',(req,res)=>{
  var abc = req.query.abc;
      console.log("abc",abc);
})

Comment: Yes i was using app.post() for http but this won't work for https. So i had to find the alternative.

Comment: yeah but its working properly now.. and check it in postman.Still u find any error then tell here..

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. The issue was with server load balancer where i was requesting. They forgot to open the port with TCP_OUT. Now it works fine.